# read an environment variable from another session

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

```
> tmux new -s test
> OK=test
> export OK
> env | grep OK
OK=test
> [control]+[B],[D]
> grep OK /proc/*/environ
> while read P ; do ps eww -p $P | grep OK; done < <(pgrep bash)
> id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

As you can see I tried 2 things but am still looking for how to read an environment variable from another session (shell instance). Only If I export and run something in tmux (like sleep 999) can i see the variable. unshare seems to have no impact.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I print a variable I can see in the output of env?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/377300)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that other than by connecting with a debugger aware of the internal structures of your shell, and using such knowledge to extract that info.

No, not even calling `getenv("OK")` or `system("printenv OK >/this/tty")` from inside it may work, because most shells don't use the standard libc functions to manage the environment, and run commands by passing the environment list explicitly as an argument to `execve()`.

The environment from `/proc/PID/environ` is that which was passed upon *starting* the process, with the observation that it could've been modified either on purpose or inadvertently by the process.

For instance, this (UB-triggering) C code will "add" an `WTF=help` to `/proc/PID/environ` which may or may not be returned by `getenv()` or passed to a child, depending on when and how `setenv()` or `putenv()` were called:

```
% cat a.c
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        memcpy(argv[argc + 1], "WTF=help", 9);
        pause();
}
% cc a.c
% ./a.out &
[4] 3445
% tr '\0' '\n' </proc/3170/environ | head -n1
WTF=help
```

Comment: `getenv("OK")` may work with *some* shells like `zsh`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have hedged my claim, feel free to edit the info about zsh in, I don't have any zsh to test on.